# Importrange query formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

[image]

HELLO 
Need help with a formula. I want to pull information from Columns 1, 11, 14 from Week 6 from all 3 sheets using the importrange formula since im putting this on another google sheet.

I have this formula currently but its not going
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https goes here from the original spreadhsheet","Sheet1!A1:U" "Sheet2!A1:U" "Sheet3!A1:U"),"Select Col1, Col11, Col14, Col21= '6'","")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1tnAtFgxCl2DnyYL0cjzijsqw8WlvC1BxI80hduaPwi0", "Sheet1!A1:U"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1tnAtFgxCl2DnyYL0cjzijsqw8WlvC1BxI80hduaPwi0", "Sheet2!A1:U"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1tnAtFgxCl2DnyYL0cjzijsqw8WlvC1BxI80hduaPwi0", "Sheet3!A1:U")}, 
 "select Col1,Col11,Col14 
  where Col21 = 6", 1)
```